# Mockito ArgumentMatcher to match only value not from the list

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

For Unit Test, is there a matcher for "value not in the List"?

**JobService.java**

```
@Service
public class JobService{
    public void job(String str1, String str2){
        //some logic to delete files
    }
}
```

**JobServiceTest.java**

```
@SpringBootTest
public class HouseServiceTest{
    @MockBean
    JobService jobService;
    
    List<String> notJob = Arrays.asList("job1", "job2", "job3");

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        doNothing().when(jobService).job(
            ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
            //how can I execute doNothing when this parameter not match with the notJob list? this 2nd parameter is the filename, so I only want to delete job1,job2, and job3 only. I don't want to delete other files.
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but generally speaking, when you whant to match that passed argument is not in the list you can use :

```
ArgumentMatchers.argThat(p -> !notJob.contains(p)))
```

Comment: the job() method is actually to delete something. so in my test case, I only want to delete files that are named as job1, job2, and job3, then those other files, don't delete.